# Angularjs ng-repeat with conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say I have 10 articles objects array and each with their own article title in it ( assume some of them has the same title )

when i do ng-repeat="art in articles" and {{ art.article_title }} it will print the title 10 times which is not what I want.

I want to do something like

Title-1:
article 1
article 2
article 3

Title-2:
article 4
article 5......

something like that if articles share the same title.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should [write a custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09), then you will be able to proceed like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="unique_article in articles|dedup">
    {{unique_article.article_title}}
    <span ng-repeat="related in unique_article.related">
        Article {{related.id}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Your filter may look for example like this (assuming your articles are sorted by title):

```
.filter('dedup', function() {
  return function(articles) {
    var deduped = [];
    var last_article = null;
    for(var i=0,max=articles.length;i<max;i++) {
        var article = articles[i];
        if(!last_article || last_article.article_title !== article.article_title)
        {
            article.related = [];
            deduped.push(article);
            last_article = article;
        } else {
            last_article.related.push(article);
        }
    }
    return deduped;
  };
});
```

(I did not test it, just written it ad hoc as a quick example, also if your articles are not sorted by title you will have to modify it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe re-thinking it would help, the ideal way to do this would be to re-arrange your object so that the articles fall under the titles, like so.

```
var arrangeArticles = function() {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.articles, function( article ) {
       var title = article.article_title;
       if( !result[title] ) {
         result[title] = [article];
       } else {
         result[title].push(article);
       }
    });
    $scope.articles = result;
    $scope.$apply(); // Might be needed 
};
```

I don't think that you can do this in the `ng-repeat`, with the layout that you expressed.

Then you would need to change your repeat to something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="(title, group) in articles">
    {{title}}
    <div ng-repeat="article in group">
       {{article.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i do that, says 3 titles and each with 10 articles in it. ng-repeat will only repeat 3 times but not looping into articles?